# Verifying a method call still passes when a failure is expected in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've just started playing around with Moq in my unit tests, but am having an issue where the unit test is passing - and I don't think it should be.

I have two objects, one that despatches data to a queue and another that implements `INotifier` which is called if the despatcher fails, they look like this (cut down for brevity):

```
public class EmailNotifier : INotifier
{
    public void Notify(string message) 
    {
        // sends the notification by email
    }
}

public class Despatcher
{
    public void Despatch(int batchNumber, INotifier failureNotifier)
    {
        try
        {
            if (batchNumber.Equals(0)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Error message");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            failureNotifier.Notify(ex.ToString());

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unit testing the `Despatcher` to specifically verify that `Notify` is being called on the provided `INotifier` (which I'm mocking) when it fails (I'm intentionally forcing the `Despatcher` to fail by passing a 0 batch number).  I set up my mocks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
public void Despatcher_notifies_on_failure()
{
    var mockNotifier = new Mock<EmailNotifier>();
    mockNotifier.Setup(n => n.Notify(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();

    var despatcher = new Despatcher();
    despatcher.Despatch(0, mockNotifier.Object);

    mockNotifier.Verify(n => n.Notify(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
}
```

This passes the test fine, which is expected as a 0 batch number raises the exception which causes the `INotifier` to call `Notify` (when I step through the test everything works as expected).

So, I go on to comment out the `failureNotifier.Notify(ex.ToString())` line and run the test again - passes fine?  I'm not sure whether I'm setting up and verifying correctly as I've only been using Moq for about 2 hours now but I thought I was understanding this correctly, but this has just thrown me a bit.  I expect this test to fail as I specifically want to make sure `Notify` is called in the event of a failure - can anyone see anything obviously wrong here?  Thanks in advance for your help as always.

Comment: Did you try using Times.Exactly(1)?

Comment: @FelicePollano I didn't, but just have and it still passes fine. I should also mention I've done the obvious of cleaning the project to make sure the older (without the `Notify` line commented) isn't being used and stepping through I can see the commented out version is being used correctly.

Comment: From my point of view your test will pass co's you expect an exception of the type `InvalidOperationException` and it is being throw.
Should you comment the  `failureNotifier.Notify(ex.ToString());` back in, your test should fail. because then there the Notify(); method call is not called.

Comment: @Syneryx this is where I'm a little confused. I'd expect the test to fail unless everything in the test passes - as I understand it I'm testing that a certain exception is thrown AND the `Notify` method's call is verified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test never gets to the verification part. Why? This line

```
despatcher.Despatch(0, mockNotifier.Object);
```

Throws exception, which is consumed by `ExpectedException` attribute and test **ends**. The `mockNotifier.Verify` line is never executed.

What you want is two *unit* tests, instead:

- one testing that notifier is called upon exception (with `.Verify`). Note that you'll have to wrap `.Despatch` call into `try { } catch { }`, so that exception is ignored.
- second, checking that exception is rethrown (with `ExpectedException`)

Comment: Of course! I just assumed that I was testing for the exception being thrown AND that my `Notify` was being called. This works a treat, thanks!